# can't uninstall an enditable pip package

Tags: python, pip

I installed a smbus2 package as editable,

`pip install -e ./smbus2-0.1.4`

Now I want to uninstall it but can't. Here is what I'm getting when I uninstall it,

```
$ pip uninstall smbus2
Can't uninstall 'smbus2'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Here is the output of `pip show --files smbus2`

```
Name: smbus2
Version: 0.1.4
Location: /home/pi/projects/smbus2-0.1.4
Requires:
Files:
Cannot locate installed-files.txt
```

What do I need to do to uninstall it and let `pip` know that it is uninstalled?

**EDIT**

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: What pip version do you use? There was an [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1895) up to at least version 8.1.1 which was recently closed as "can't reproduce".

Comment: @0range Just made and edit adding the output of `pip --version`. Can I be this far behind?

Comment: According to the [release notes](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/) 1.5.6 would be 3 years old. Depending on what kind of system you are on, that is not impossibly far behind.